# get a value from json decoded array

Tags: php, json

I have this json encoded string

```
{"allresponses":"{\"id\":\"123456\",\"recipients\":1}"}
```

and I have to get the id only and pass it to a php variable.

This is what I'm trying:
suppose I have that string in variable return, so:

```
$return = '{"allresponses":"{\"id\":\"123456\",\"recipients\":1}"}';
$getid = json_decode($return,true);
echo $getid[0]['id'];
```

This is not working; I get fatal error. Can you tell me why? What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got json-in-json, which means that the value for `allresponses` is itself a json string, and has to be decoded separately:

```
$return = '{"allresponses":"{\"id\":\"123456\",\"recipients\":1}"}';
$temp = json_decode($return);

$allresp = $temp['allresponses'];
$temp2 = json_decode($allresp);

echo $temp2['id']; // 123456
```

Note that your `$getid[0]` is WRONG. You don't have an array. The json is purely objects (`{...}`), therefore there's no `[0]` index to access. Even some basic debugging like `var_dump($getid)` would have shown you this.

Comment: Obviously, this madness should be fixed at the source, not by double decoding…

Comment: the problem is i use an API that gives me that source, so i can't fix it, lol. About $getid[0] , i used "true" in json_encode statement to make it as associated array, shouldn't it be converted form obj to array then? Ayway, i'm getting Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: it'll be a php array, but that still doesn't create a `[0]` index.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. adding ",true" at every json_decode , fixes the problem. :)

Comment: ah yeah. you have to DECODE to an assoc array: `json_decode(...,true)` as well. JS doesn't have associated arrays. it has objects. arrays are ALWAYS numerical-keyed, sequentially. if you have an array missing indexes, then it HAS to be encoded as an object.